# Cross-platform screenshot

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am looking for a library (or just a code snippet) to take screenshots (simple still image, not video)? Preferably open source / cross-platform. Is it something what is possible with OpenCV? Thanks!

Comment: OpenCV can't do that. Definitely.

Comment: And while you specifically say still images, I'll tell you about VLC. It can record videos, so, maybe it is able to save images, too.

Comment: @vasile whenever you have video you have images :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. VLC looks promising, I will take a look..

Comment: hey kalman, are you related to that mathematician that wrote the kalman ecuations? By the way, it's a difference between video and images. To extract a picture from a video file may not be the most intuitive task. So, I have emphasized the possible minus of my tool.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not related to that mathematician. ;) Currently I am playing with VLC, the video streaming capabilities are very good! But you are right getting still frames from the video stream probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You could also use QT to take a screenshots](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.3.2/desktop-screenshot.html) (since the question is short and not very clear I can only assume that this is what you meant).

Answer (score 2):

You can use SDL
It is cross-platform and open source...